# How to delete a data automatically from a document in MongoDB after some specified time

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

One of my fields is an Array in the MongoDB document.
I want an element to be deleted from that array after a specified time.
How do I do that?

I tried mongo TTL but it deletes the entire document.

Comment: Nothing built-in, AFAIK. You either implement periodic cleanup jobs in your application, or reshape your data so that elements of that array are their own top-level documents in a TTL collection.

Comment: I guess you may try task scheduler. There are some packages also available to make your life easy.

Comment: There's no real way to do this directly - either you use a task scheduler or you break out the array into its own collection and use TTL. If you're using Mongoose it's easy to have multiple documents referenced together despite being in different collections.

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB doesn't have a feature that does what you're asking.

Create a job (e.g., CRON job in Linux, Scheduled Task in Windows) that executes a script, which removes the property. The script can take a variety of approaches. You can have another collection that identifies documents you haven't updated (or have updated). You may need to bake in some indexing changes. You could restructure your schema to make the array its own document; Sergio Tulentsev's suggestion. But, you get the gist. You'll need to build the logic yourself.

Comment: mongoDB have this feature and you can try expireAfterSeconds

Comment: @MARahman `expireAfterSeconds` is associated with MongoDB's data expiration feature, which removes a document after a given period; see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/expire-data/. The requester wants to remove an element from a document not remove the document from the collection, "...I want an element to be deleted from that array..." They already tried data expiration but said it didn't suite their purpose, "I tried mongo TTL but it deletes the entire document."

Comment: @MARahman I think you misread the question. Adam is right. Looks like Kunal wants to delete an element from an array in a document not the whole document. +1'ed this.